# Cannot codesign an app with Python and Node

Tags: python, node.js, macos, pyinstaller, codesign

I have a fairly large and complex app. It's about 550 megs uncompressed with about 36,000 files. Since the main source code is in Python, I use `pyInstaller` to create the initial .app file. I then copy everything else the app needs (docs, samples, `node_modules`, etc.) into the `Content/MacOS` subfolder in the `XXX.app` file. (Yup, it uses `node` too.)

The .app works properly - but needs to be signed. According to Apple, it's not enough simply sign `XXX.app`: all of the components in it also need to be signed. I tried that route first - but it seems every .txt, .png and all other files need to be signed. That's 36,000 `codesign` commands!

The other choice is to use `codesign`'s `--deep` option. Apple warns in [TN2206](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG404):

> Important: While the --deep option can be applied to a signing
>   operation, this is not recommended. We recommend that you sign code
>   inside out in individual stages (as Xcode does automatically). Signing
>   with --deep is for emergency repairs and temporary adjustments only.

Going down this path regardless, it seems that many of the components can't be signed by codesign:

```
"bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
In subcomponent: /Users/george/Files/dist/XXX.app/Contents/MacOS/node/node_modules/lodash.debounce"
```

My assumption is that `codesign` can't deal with certain component names, such as `lodash.debounce`, `20140401180856!About.png` or `.bin.`

How the heck can I sign this app?

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html) ?

Comment: Yes, in fact I link to that document in my question. Is there something specific in that document I may have missed?

Answer (score 3):

It's all sorted out. There were a number of things which needed to be fixed. Here they are, in the hope they will help someone else in the future. Apple's [TN2206](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG404) is full of good advice and worth understanding.

√ Get everything that isn't a library connected to your main executable out of your `Contents/MacOS` folder. Move it to `Contents/Resources` and set symbolic links.

√ If you're using Node, it should be in Contents/Resources. Set a link from `Contents/MacOS` like this, while you are in the `Contents/MacOS` folder:

```
ln -s ../Resources/node node
```

√ Links need to be relative, since the app needs to be portable. When it's installed on another system, the full path won't be the same.

√ Don't use the `--deep` flag, even though it's tempting. I needed 110 `codesign` statements, one for each library. Python is considered a library:

```
codesign --force --verify --verbose=4 --sign "Developer ID Application: NS BASIC Corporation" ~/Files/dist/AppStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

√ After you've done a `codesign` for each library, `codesign` the app itself:

```
codesign --force --verify --verbose=4 --sign "Developer ID Application: NS BASIC Corporation" ~/Files/dist/AppStudio.app
```

Then verify that it worked properly:

```
codesign --display --verbose=4 ~/Files/dist/AppStudio.app
```

√ If you see a message like

```
"code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/george/Files/dist/AppStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/_Ctl.so"
```

That means you missed a library.

√ If you get a message like this:

```
"bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
In subcomponent: /Users/george/Files/dist/AppStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/node/node_modules/.bin"
```

It's not a library. Get it out of `Contents/MacOS`, move it to `Contents/Resources` and set up a symbolic link. (I'm looking at you, `cacert.pem`!)

√ Once you think you have it, use this command to check the final app:

```
codesign --vvvv AppStudio.app
```

Good luck with your project!